# Overwritting data with Pandas to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to import my pandas dataframe to BigQuery, but always that I try the code insert more rows when I want to overwrite it.

```
client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = 'getdata-345817.get_data.fbinsights'

write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, table_id
)  
job.result()  

table = client.get_table(table_id)
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```

I've tried "write_truncate" but can't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved inserting:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        write_disposition=bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
    )
```

I hope this solution help other programmers with the same issue.